All values reset when EditForm has OnValidSubmit
I have a Blazor component. An Id is passed in but when the OnValidSubmit of the edit form fires first it runs 'OnInitializedAsync()' as expected.
I set a parameter first to true on the page load and set that to false the first run through 'OnInitializedAsync()'.
However this value is always true so the values I want to get on only the first page load are all reset and what the user entered is ignored.
I've looked at what the scaffolder made previously (though for some reason it's not currently working) and it looks like it should work.
ChatGPT and examples online seem the same.
How can I only fire the initial get of the data on the first page load?
Thanks.
@page "/myprediction/edit/{id}"
@using FootballHeadzGame.Data
@using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
@* @inject FootballHeadz3.Data.ApplicationDbContext DB *@
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager
@inject IPredictionRepository _predictionRepository
@attribute [Authorize]

<PageTitle>Edit Prediction</PageTitle>

@if (_predictionToEdit is null)
{
    <p><em>Loading...</em></p>
}
else
{
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
            <h1>Edit Prediction</h1>
        </div>
        <MessageComponent Message="@_message" MessageError="@_messageError" />
        <div class="card-body">
            <EditForm FormName="Prediction" Model="_predictionToEdit" OnValidSubmit="UpdatePrediction" class="row row-cols-sm-auto g-1 align-items-center">
                <div>
                    <DataAnnotationsValidator />
                    <ValidationSummary />
                </div>
                <div class="col-6">
                    <label class="visually-hidden" for="inlineFormInputGroupUsername">Home Team</label>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <div class="input-group-text">@_predictionToEdit.HomeTeam</div>
                        <InputText @bind-Value="_predictionToEdit.HomeScorePredictionString" style="width:40px;" class="form-control"></InputText>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-6">
                    <label class="visually-hidden" for="inlineFormInputGroupUsername">Away Team</label>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <InputText @bind-Value="_predictionToEdit.AwayScorePredictionString" style="width:40px;" class="form-control"></InputText>
                        <div class="input-group-text">@_predictionToEdit.AwayTeam</div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-12">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primaryfh">Update</button>
                </div>
            </EditForm>
        </div>
    </div>
}


@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [CascadingParameter]
    Task<AuthenticationState> authenticationStateTask { get; set; }

    private string? _message;
    private string? _messageError;
    //private FixtureModel _predictionToEdit;

    [SupplyParameterFromForm]
    private PredictionModel _predictionToEdit { get; set; } = new();

    private int userId;

    private bool first { get; set; } = true;



    // [SupplyParameterFromForm]
    // public MiniLeagueModel? MiniLeagueModel { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        // This is always zero not sure why
        //if (_predictionToEdit.UserId == 0)
        if (first)
        {
            var authState = await authenticationStateTask;
            userId = Convert.ToInt32(authState.User.Claims.FirstOrDefault().Value);

            _predictionToEdit.UserId = userId;
            _predictionToEdit.FixtureId = Convert.ToInt32(Id);

            // I'm not passing a prediction model in here because it passes it out and it would be a mess
            _predictionToEdit = await _predictionRepository.GetAsync(userId, Convert.ToInt32(Id));

            _message = userId.ToString() + ". " + Id;
            first = false;
        }
    }


    private async Task UpdatePrediction()
    {
        await ClearMessages();

        if (_predictionToEdit.HomeScorePredictionString == null || _predictionToEdit.AwayScorePredictionString == null)
        {
            //var isNumeric = int.TryParse("123", out _);
            //if (int.TryParse())
            _messageError = "You must fill in the score";
        }
        else
        {
            _predictionToEdit.HomeScorePrediction = Convert.ToInt32(_predictionToEdit.HomeScorePredictionString);
            _predictionToEdit.AwayScorePrediction = Convert.ToInt32(_predictionToEdit.AwayScorePredictionString);
            await _predictionRepository.UpdateAsync(_predictionToEdit);

            NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/mypredictions");
        }

    }

    private async Task ClearMessages()
    {
        _message = null;
        _messageError = null;
    }

}


Is it SSR rendermode?

Yes, can you use SSR to edit values in a form?

If you are not using SSR, you could use OnAfterRender(bool first) to check first load.
If you use SSR. the "first" value is not saved when submit. You could try use server session storage to save the "first" value for check. And the session storage will be clear when session ends.
    [CascadingParameter]
    HttpContext? httpContext { get; set; }

    protected override void OnInitialized(){

        if (httpContext.Session.GetInt32("first")==null)
        {
            ...reset value.....

            httpContext.Session.SetInt32("first",1);
        }
    }

program.cs
...
builder.Services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
builder.Services.AddSession();
...
app.UseSession();


Thanks so to use this with SSR I'd need to use OnAfterRender(bool first) if I want to only load the existing values on the first load?

@nicc I mean you can't use onAfterrender with SSR. You need to try with session. Another way to keep the "first" value is you could put it in the model. So the "first" is also submitted.
